# Javascript error caused by large dictionary

Tags: javascript, dictionary

I'm trying to add the following large dictionary to my Javascript code:

```
lang_mappings = {
    'ab': 'Abkhaz',
    'aa': 'Afar',
    'af': 'Afrikaans',
    'ak': 'Akan',
    'sq': 'Albanian',
    'am': 'Amharic',
    'ar': 'Arabic',
    'an': 'Aragonese',
    'hy': 'Armenian',
    'as': 'Assamese',
    'av': 'Avaric',
    'ae': 'Avestan',
    'ay': 'Aymara',
    'az': 'Azerbaijani',
    'bm': 'Bambara',
    'ba': 'Bashkir',
    'eu': 'Basque',
    'be': 'Belarusian',
    'bn': 'Bengali',
    'bh': 'Bihari',
    'bi': 'Bislama',
    'bs': 'Bosnian',
    'br': 'Breton',
    'bg': 'Bulgarian',
    'my': 'Burmese',
    'ca': 'Catalan; Valencian',
    'ch': 'Chamorro',
    'ce': 'Chechen',
    'ny': 'Chichewa; Chewa; Nyanja',
    'zh': 'Chinese',
    'cv': 'Chuvash',
    'kw': 'Cornish',
    'co': 'Corsican',
    'cr': 'Cree',
    'hr': 'Croatian',
    'cs': 'Czech',
    'da': 'Danish',
    'dv': 'Divehi; Maldivian;',
    'nl': 'Dutch',
    'dz': 'Dzongkha',
    'en': 'English',
    'eo': 'Esperanto',
    'et': 'Estonian',
    'ee': 'Ewe',
    'fo': 'Faroese',
    'fj': 'Fijian',
    'fi': 'Finnish',
    'fr': 'French',
    'ff': 'Fula',
    'gl': 'Galician',
    'ka': 'Georgian',
    'de': 'German',
    'el': 'Greek, Modern',
    'gn': 'Guaraní',
    'gu': 'Gujarati',
    'ht': 'Haitian',
    'ha': 'Hausa',
    'he': 'Hebrew (modern)',
    'hz': 'Herero',
    'hi': 'Hindi',
    'ho': 'Hiri Motu',
    'hu': 'Hungarian',
    'ia': 'Interlingua',
    'id': 'Indonesian',
    'ie': 'Interlingue',
    'ga': 'Irish',
    'ig': 'Igbo',
    'ik': 'Inupiaq',
    'io': 'Ido',
    'is': 'Icelandic',
    'it': 'Italian',
    'iu': 'Inuktitut',
    'ja': 'Japanese',
    'jv': 'Javanese',
    'kl': 'Kalaallisut',
    'kn': 'Kannada',
    'kr': 'Kanuri',
    'ks': 'Kashmiri',
    'kk': 'Kazakh',
    'km': 'Khmer',
    'ki': 'Kikuyu, Gikuyu',
    'rw': 'Kinyarwanda',
    'ky': 'Kirghiz, Kyrgyz',
    'kv': 'Komi',
    'kg': 'Kongo',
    'ko': 'Korean',
    'ku': 'Kurdish',
    'kj': 'Kwanyama, Kuanyama',
    'la': 'Latin',
    'lb': 'Luxembourgish',
    'lg': 'Luganda',
    'li': 'Limburgish',
    'ln': 'Lingala',
    'lo': 'Lao',
    'lt': 'Lithuanian',
    'lu': 'Luba-Katanga',
    'lv': 'Latvian',
    'gv': 'Manx',
    'mk': 'Macedonian',
    'mg': 'Malagasy',
    'ms': 'Malay',
    'ml': 'Malayalam',
    'mt': 'Maltese',
    'mi': 'Māori',
    'mr': 'Marathi (Marāṭhī)',
    'mh': 'Marshallese',
    'mn': 'Mongolian',
    'na': 'Nauru',
    'nv': 'Navajo, Navaho',
    'nb': 'Norwegian Bokmål',
    'nd': 'North Ndebele',
    'ne': 'Nepali',
    'ng': 'Ndonga',
    'nn': 'Norwegian Nynorsk',
    'no': 'Norwegian',
    'ii': 'Nuosu',
    'nr': 'South Ndebele',
    'oc': 'Occitan',
    'oj': 'Ojibwe, Ojibwa',
    'cu': 'Old Church Slavonic',
    'om': 'Oromo',
    'or': 'Oriya',
    'os': 'Ossetian, Ossetic',
    'pa': 'Panjabi, Punjabi',
    'pi': 'Pāli',
    'fa': 'Persian',
    'pl': 'Polish',
    'ps': 'Pashto, Pushto',
    'pt': 'Portuguese',
    'qu': 'Quechua',
    'rm': 'Romansh',
    'rn': 'Kirundi',
    'ro': 'Romanian, Moldavan',
    'ru': 'Russian',
    'sa': 'Sanskrit (Saṁskṛta)',
    'sc': 'Sardinian',
    'sd': 'Sindhi',
    'se': 'Northern Sami',
    'sm': 'Samoan',
    'sg': 'Sango',
    'sr': 'Serbian',
    'gd': 'Scottish Gaelic',
    'sn': 'Shona',
    'si': 'Sinhala, Sinhalese',
    'sk': 'Slovak',
    'sl': 'Slovene',
    'so': 'Somali',
    'st': 'Southern Sotho',
    'es': 'Spanish; Castilian',
    'su': 'Sundanese',
    'sw': 'Swahili',
    'ss': 'Swati',
    'sv': 'Swedish',
    'ta': 'Tamil',
    'te': 'Telugu',
    'tg': 'Tajik',
    'th': 'Thai',
    'ti': 'Tigrinya',
    'bo': 'Tibetan',
    'tk': 'Turkmen',
    'tl': 'Tagalog',
    'tn': 'Tswana',
    'to': 'Tonga',
    'tr': 'Turkish',
    'ts': 'Tsonga',
    'tt': 'Tatar',
    'tw': 'Twi',
    'ty': 'Tahitian',
    'ug': 'Uighur, Uyghur',
    'uk': 'Ukrainian',
    'ur': 'Urdu',
    'uz': 'Uzbek',
    've': 'Venda',
    'vi': 'Vietnamese',
    'vo': 'Volapük',
    'wa': 'Walloon',
    'cy': 'Welsh',
    'wo': 'Wolof',
    'fy': 'Western Frisian',
    'xh': 'Xhosa',
    'yi': 'Yiddish',
    'yo': 'Yoruba',
    'za': 'Zhuang, Chuang',
    'zu': 'Zulu'
}
```

Unfortunately, my browser console throws an the following error when I do so:

UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 2078: character maps to undefined

I think it's because some of the language names have special characters. Is there any way around this?

Comment: Make sure you save the file as UTF-8 in your editor.

Comment: Save the file in the correct encoding (whatever encoding your web servers advertises it as).

Comment: I pasted that collection into my chrome console and it worked fine, I suspect the problem may be in the code that is trying to utilise that collection. Could you provide some related code to look at?

Comment: @AlexanderDeSousa got me in a sec.
did the same thing and it worked.

Comment: my code doesn't use the dictionary currently

Comment: If you're getting an error without that bit of code then it would suggest that collection is not the issue.

Comment: That looks like a Phyton error, are you using Python to do something? If so it's more likely you should persue a solution in Python, this is the most relevant documentation I have found on that error for your situation: https://wiki.python.org/moin/UnicodeDecodeError

Comment: Do you have `<meta charset="UTF-8">` meta element in head section of your html document?

Comment: @RishikeshAgrawani If it's an external js file, the encoding of the html document doesn't matter

Comment: Can you add more details about your question? Do you have the above dictionary in any python file? If you are using any framework of Python then which one? What's your idea to use it in JavaScript?